# CoucheBase winform not able to connect on remote client in the same network

Tags: .net, couchbase

I have sucessfully setup a couchbase instance on a Windows 2012 r2 server.

I have a .net winform app connecting to it.

When I try yo access the UI ON 192.168.x.x than I am able to reach it via the browser.

However when connecting to it via the winform app, it is only working on the database server itself, not on other client on the network. Any ideas what could cause this? I am connecting to the ser by adding the uri in de clientConfiguration...

Any ideas?

Comment: The browser and client run on different ports. Add your code, please

Answer (score 0):

Check that the necessary network ports are configured to accept traffic: [Network Configuration](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/install-ports.html)

Or have a look at this related question: [Access Couchbase on Azure Windows 2012 VM from .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811551/access-couchbase-on-azure-windows-2012-vm-from-net)